# Create multiple objects of a particular class using @Component annotation in Spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-annotations

Can we create multiple objects of a particular class (for instance class Student) using `@Component` Annotation, since there can be only 1 String passed to `@Component` Annotation (`@Component("Student1")`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The `@Component` annotation tells Spring that a single instance of the class should be created. The value you pass in the annotation reflects the name of the "Spring bean".

If you want to create multiple instances, you can use the `@Bean` annotation in a `@Configuration` class:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public Student student1() {
    return new Student();
  }

  @Bean
  public Student student2() {
    return new Student();
  }
}
```

This code would create 2 Spring beans in the Spring context. One with the `student1` name and the other with the `student2` name.

Note that you usually would not do this for objects like `Student` which are probably entities (most likely reflecting what you have in your database if you use a database in your application).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that literally cleared my doubt!

Comment: 'The @Component annotation tells Spring that a single instance of the class should be created' - assuming singleton scope